# How to make a decimal random number generator in c++?

Tags: c++

I tried to make a decimal random number generator the user enters the min and max

I looked at other questions and answers but they either don't have min and max or don't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;    
int main(){
    int low;
    int high;
    cout<<"what is the lowest number?";
    cin>>low;
    cout<<"what is the highest number?";
    cin>>high;
    high++;
    low++;
    double random;
    srand( unsigned(time(NULL) ));
    random=(double)rand()/(RAND_MAX+1)*(high-low)+low;
    cout<<random;
}
```

after I put in parameters of 1(min) and 10(max), I expected the number that the compiler gave out to be like 1.346 but it was a random negative decimal number

Comment: Simply use what's already provided by the standard library: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: `RAND_MAX+1` is probably causing an overflow. Delete the `+1`

Comment: @NikBrusilovski That's why I posted a comment and I didn't post that as an answer. So why bothering?

Comment: With the given code, if I input `1` and `10`, then `1.346` is not a valid result, because it's less than the `low` of 2, but `10.98` is a valid result.  Why did you increment `high` and `low`?

Comment: @NikBrusilovski: The best way to attract upvotes would be to spruce up the question: e.g. submit a compilable example from `int main()`. Then document the actual result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue, unless you've entered in pathological values for `low` and `high`, is that `RAND_MAX + 1` is likely to overflow the `int` type, and so the behaviour of your program is *undefined* (wrap around to INT_MIN is a common manifestation and would account for what you observe).

But given that solution using `rand()` will invariably have bias anyway, consider

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 eng(rd());
std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist(low, high); // the range - does not include high
```

and draw a number with `dist(eng)`. Drop the increments of `low` and `high`.

Comment: he need `uniform_real_distribution` he messed up types used for input.

Comment: @MarekR: Oops. Let's publish jointly!

Comment: @NikBrusilovski Indeed! The C++11 standard was a quantum leap forward.